# White Screen of Death

Tags: magento-1.9, error, xml, frontend, log

Good morning community.
Yesterday my Magento went **WSoD** on me, while trying to make some changes so it works the way my boss wants it to.
The problem started appearing after I turned on the "add storecode to URL" option.
At first I noticed the extension "Advanced Permissions with Multi-Vendor" wasn't working properly anymore (user login produced PHP error all of a sudden).
After trying to fix the problem by disabling the storecode-option again, I got the WSoD.

**What I've tried so far:**
Clearing and disabling Cache; Disabling compiler, edit index.php (display_errors and memory_limit), check the XML files for changes in the last 15 minutes.

Obviously nothing has worked so far. I've downloaded my **system.log** and mostly cleared it.
Yes, I do have the old version still, but I uploaded the almost empty one, so I could actually find the log entry.
After reloading the page, here it is:

```
2014-10-28T08:00:48+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant tmp - assumed 'tmp'  in /home/.sites/147/site9663270/web/shop/lib/Zend/Cache.php on line 153
2014-10-28T08:00:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 108: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: value line 108 and image  in /home/.sites/147/site9663270/web/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2014-10-28T08:00:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                 &lt;action method=&quot;setElementClass&quot;&gt;&lt;value&gt;newsletterimage&lt;/image&gt;&lt;  in /home/.sites/147/site9663270/web/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2014-10-28T08:00:48+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /home/.sites/147/site9663270/web/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
```

**Anyone know what this means?** I suppose something with xml-files.

**edit01:** After some help from Stefan Gregori, I fixed the tmp-folder warning, here's the new log:

```
2014-10-28T09:20:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 108: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: value line 108 and image  in /home/.sites/147/site9663270/web/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2014-10-28T09:20:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                 &lt;action method=&quot;setElementClass&quot;&gt;&lt;value&gt;newsletterimage&lt;/image&gt;&lt;  in /home/.sites/147/site9663270/web/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2014-10-28T09:20:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                                ^  in /home/.sites/147/site9663270/web/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
```

Comment: In Cache.php you use tmp (as variable - i guess its empty) instead of 'tmp' (string folder name) so magento will not be able to find your tmp-folder.

Comment: I am confused about that :D ... You mean BackendSettings? Because this folder name is hard-coded in the file mentioned in your log.

Comment: Ah got an idea. Look at lib/Mage/Cache/Backend/File.php ... think thats the right file. Search for cache_dir.

Comment: found it. it wasn't in "Mage", it was in "Zend"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from your error message it looks like some badly formatted layout xml.

Try looking for the file with thee snippet `newsletterimage`. In here you will probably find the error.

Have a look for opening tags, encoding issues or something else that is cause the error in your xml.

Comment: That fixed it for me. Thanks a lot! It seems I forgot about that one when I reverted the changes. I owe you.

Comment: can someone upvote this guy's answer for me please? Or upvote my question so I can upvote the answer myself (15 reputation and stuff)